# Image size control in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, static-resources, images

I have below page where I want to reduce the image size but the height and width is not working here. It is not controllable and occupies the whole page area. Can someone let me know how to control it?

**Apex Page:**

```
<apex:page>
<img src="{!$Resource.Sign}" width="100%" height="60%"/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use apex component, native HTML needs additional processing to be displayed correctly.

Try:

```
<apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.army}" width="25%" height="25%"/>
```